# Integrate Shopify store in React Native

Tags: react-native, shopify

I already have a React Native application, and want to integrate an existing Shopify store in a screen into it. Is there an easy wat to do that? if it's possible can I reuse an existing Shopify theme?

I found this site https://instamobile.io/app-templates/react-native-shopify-app/ which sells a react native template to integrate Shopify store, but it has two problems:

1. I need to create a new application with the template, which is not the best fit to me
2. I need to spend $300 to get that template

Also I know I can use Storefront API to receive items, but I don't want to spend a lot of time integrating it.

Comment: if your store is responsive then you can just use the web-view to show your website,
rer: https://archive.reactnative.dev/docs/webview